Renamed a project but the old name still affects the target
How to change the two places in the screen shots that are still the old name?
Hello, a novice here.  The project was first renamed by a global cmmd F (a major mess up that led to a sea of red).  Xcode is saying "the active scheme has no target".  I tried my best to change all the old names but came across these two places that still use the old name (eg "A B C" with spaces, new name is "ABC" no space).


Any advice helps. Thanks!

At least you can recreate the scheme(s). Click on Manage Schemes and then on Autocreate Schemes Now. And did you rename the target, too?

I have now.  Thank you!  I have tried every other place and for some reason I did not notice it until I search a video on how to rename the target.

@vadian Hello, if you would like, I can green check your reply if you put it in the answer. Thank you.

Renaming a project
If you want to rename an Xcode Project, do it via the Project Navigator, and change the name of the label for the top item.
It will rename the project file on disk, and also provide UX to make sure it updates all the internal references.
Renaming a Target
Same approach as renaming the project... but it this case, there are often minor conflicts which need to be repaired by hand.
(this is probably the place you broke several file references in the project).
Also, it goes without saying, save a copy before you make such a big change... git or even a quick folder copy… they are your friends!
